# "minimal" polynomial decomposition similar to partial fraction decomposition

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials

This question is motivated by the fact that we can write any rational function $f$ on $\mathbb{C}$ as
$$f(z) = g(z)+\dfrac{p(z)}{q(z)}$$
where $g,p,q$ are polynomials with $\mathrm{deg}(p)\leq \mathrm{deg}(q)$. Now, we can develop $\dfrac{p}{q}$ via partial fraction decomposition as
$$\dfrac{p(z)}{q(z)}=\sum_{i}\dfrac{s_i}{(\xi_i-z)^{n_i}}$$
with $s_i\in\mathbb{C}$ and $\xi_i$ the zeros of $q$. I want to bring $f$ in a form which looks like a generalized Laurent polynomial expansion, i.e., there are finitely many non-zero values $s_i,\xi_{i}\in\mathbb{C}$ and $n_i\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that
$$f(z)=\sum_{i\in\mathbb{Z}} s_i(\xi_i-z)^{n_i}$$
and $n_i<0$ iff $i<0$ as well as
$$\sum_{i<0} s_i(\xi_i-z)^{n_i}=\dfrac{p(z)}{q(z)}.$$
Inversely, this implies that
$$g(z) = \sum_{i\geq 0} s_i(\xi_i-z)^{n_i}$$
which is in contrast to the partial fraction decompositon of the fractional part not unique. Is there a sensible notion of minimality in the values $s_i,\xi_i$ such that this decomposition of $g$ becomes unique? Defining $s^{{\geq 0}},\xi^{\geq 0}$ as the vectors with entries $s_i,\xi_i$ with posiitve index $i$, my only idea was to use simply ad hoc the euclidean norm on $\mathbb{C}^N$ and minimize $||s^{{\geq 0}}||^2||\xi^{\geq 0}||^2$ under the constraint
$$g(z) = \sum_{i\geq 0} s_i(\xi_i-z)^{n_i}.$$